# Will mongoDB restrict DBA from accessing encrypted data if encryption is enabled

Tags: mongodb, encryption

I have been reading about Data encryption at rest feature in MongoDB. I understand that plain text data is encrypted using database key and it is stored in disk. Lets say if any DBA connects to the database and executes a query to retrieve the data from DB. Will this data be in decrypted form. Is there any restriction imposed on such operations where DBA is prompted to enter the key ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Encrypted Storage Engine" of Mongo encrypts data only on file level. This means it is encrypted when written into a database storage file and decrypted when it is read.

On database level (and on transport level) the data is again plain. Therefore any DBA will not see a difference whether the database is encrypted or not.

This type of encryption is designed to prevent data theft/leakage when someone manages to access the file-system data (or a backup of it) where your Mongo server stores the database files.

What you are looking for is an "Application Level Encryption" solution. Usually such a solution will be integrated into your "database client application" (from the perspective of the Mongo Server).

Comment: In this link https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/securing-mongodb-part-3-database-auditing-and-encryption , it is mentioned that "This new storage engine provides an additional level of defense, allowing only those staff with the appropriate database credentials access to encrypted data." . So, I was wondering if there is any restrictions that can be put on DBA as well.

Comment: You misinterpret the sentence: It means "anybody who has access credentials can read all data the credentials grant access to". An DBA has admin credentials which allows reading/writing every data in the database. There nothing like a "deny access permission" in Mongo.  As I wrote you need an additional application level encryption for preventing DBAs to access the data.